# How to make a footer on WordPress align centered on mobile but on one line on desktop and tablet view

Tags: php, css, wordpress, formatting

I am trying to make my footer on one line on desktop and centered on mobile. However, the picture on the footer is aligned left and not center on mobile. I'm wondering any tips on how to fix this issue. 
Here is the code that I currently have for the site:

hose don't seem to make a change. Any tips are appreciated

Comment: It's an <a> tag. Simple `text-align: center` on the parent should do. No floating, no padding and most definitly no `display: inline`. Parent has to be `block`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a couple of tweaks I ran and got it to work in the browser when going to your site.

For desktop CSS:

```
.nonprofit {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    /* padding-left: 200px; */ // remove this
    display: block;
    align: right;
    float: left; // Keep this in there
    width: 50%; // Do this instead of width 100%
}
```

For your mobile CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
.nonprofit {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    /* float: left; */ // remove this
    width: 100%; // add this
}
```

Comment: If you're going to be using a lot of custom styling with CSS I would strongly urge you to get away from using floats. Take a look at Flexbox. It was literally created because of how bad floats are to work with in making the so-called "God Layout."
[Link to Great Flexbox Article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: thanks for your answer! This helps a lot, I'm wondering if you can keep the text and the logo on the same line for the desktop version and switch it to what you have it as for mobile

Comment: @mike I've made edits to the two snippets. I put back the float left and made it width 50%. After trying that I think it will do what you're looking for.